# How to make button like radiobuttons in PyQt?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt

I can't seem to figure out how I could do something like this in PyQt. It makes the radiobuttons, more like buttons (this is tkinter)
[image]

```
   Radiobutton(root, 
                text=txt,
                indicatoron = 0,
                width = 20,
                padx = 20, 
                variable=v, 
                command=ShowChoice,
                value=val).pack(anchor=W)
```

Comment: I don't think so, you have to design them yourself or you can simply use buttons with some radio button logic. It won't be hard to implement.

Comment: How is what you're doing different than what you expect? Your code looks ok to me, though you're obviously only showing one button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a [QButtonGroup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qbuttongroup.html)? It's exclusive by default and helps you keeping track and reacting on the events when you click on an option.

Code example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])

w = QWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('pyqt')
l = QVBoxLayout(w)
l.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
l.addWidget(QLabel('Choose your favorite programming language:'))

titles = ['Python', 'Perl', 'Java', 'C++', 'C']
buttons = [QPushButton(title) for title in titles]

button_group = QButtonGroup()

for button in buttons:
    l.addWidget(button)
    button_group.addButton(button)
    button.setCheckable(True)

w.show()
app.exec()
```

which looks like your example except for differences in style (use [Qt stylesheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/stylesheet.html) for that).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!